# Multiple projects using the same module under heavy development

Tags: node.js, git, deployment, module, npm

I have a series of applications, called `app1`, `app2`, `app3` running on my server. They are all Github repos.
All of them depend on on a module, `changing-module`, that is under heavy development. The module is published on npm.

I am having trouble deciding how to deploy the apps as well as the module. Please note that I have TWENTY modules under heavy development, not just one.

Possible solutions:

1) Deploy `changing-module` using NPM. **Pros:** Easy to do. **Cons:** It requires me to do a npm update for `changing-module` manually, for app1, app2 and app3. It also means that I must do `npm publish` on *every* application for *every* changing module every time I make an important change

2) Have `changing-module` checked out, and use symlinks to it. This implies that I install the apps with a `git checkout`/`npm install`, but THEN I take out the NPM modules and replace them with symlinks. **Pros:** Any change to the repo is immediately visible to all of the apps. **Cons:** this is a problem because `changing-module` has dependencies, and the dependencies *actually* present under `node_modules` tend to depend on the app (because of deduping etc.).

3) Have `changing-module` as a git repository in each app. This implies that I install the apps with a `git checkout`/`npm install`, but THEN I swap the npm repositories with the git repository, _keeping node_modules intact as it is_. **Pros:** No mess with npm dependencies within `changing-module` **Cons:** Need to do a `git pull` on *every* application for *every* changing module every time I make an important change.

The ideal solution is (2), since I really want my app to use the latest changes of `changing-module`. However, I am not sure how I should deal with the dependencies issue.

How do you do this?